# How to sort array with respect to distance calculated from latitude and longitude.

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have an array of custom object. And the object have parameters including latitude and longitude. I want to sort that array with respect to distance of them from the current location. 
I can able to get the distance between the current location and each object. But I dont know how to sort it after calculating the distance. 
For Eg:

```
MainArray = [{name:NYC, lat:1.11, lng:2.22}, {name:CAL, lat:3.33, lng:4.44}, {name:LA, lat:5.55, lng:6.66}].
```

So lets say am in centre of three places and then I want to sort them in the nearby order. Sorry if the above syntax is wrong, as I cant post the original data because it is too big.

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the same as previous answer but without adding field:

```
CLLocation *yourLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:.... longitude:...];
NSArray *array = @[@{ @"name": @"NYC", @"lat": @1.11, @"lng": @2.22}, @{@"name":@"CAL", @"lat":@3.33, @"lng":@4.44}, @{@"name":@"LA", @"lat":@5.55, @"lng":@6.66}];
array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[obj1[@"lat"] double]  longitude:[obj1[@"lng"] double]];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[obj2[@"lat"] double]  longitude:[obj2[@"lng"] double]];

    CLLocationDistance distance1 = [location1 distanceFromLocation:yourLocation];
    CLLocationDistance distance2 = [location2 distanceFromLocation:yourLocation];

    if (distance1 > distance2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (distance1 < obj2 distance2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field in your object named *distanceFromLocation*.

Then just before you need to display the distances, update the *distanceFromLocation* in the array of your objects using below code.

```
 CLLocation *arrayCoord = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *yourLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:yourLocationLat longitude:yourLocationLong];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [arrayCoord distanceFromLocation:yourLocation];
```

After that sort your array of objects using sort descriptors

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distanceFromLocation"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfYourObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```